# Why is the program giving me warning,incompatible declaration of built in function

Tags: c

This is a menu driven program that allows a user to:

(1)view a calendar

(2)view on which day of the week a particular date falls

(3)exit the program.

But its not running please help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

#include<math.h>

void load_menu();
void view_calender();
void view_date();``

int main (int argv, char** arv)
{
load_menu();
return ;
}
void load_menu()
{
int choice;

do
{
    printf("Menu\n");
    printff("1. View Calender\n");
    printf("2. View on which day a particular dau falls\n");
    printf("3. Exit Programme\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: view_calender();
            break;
        case 2: view_date();
            break;
        case 3: printf("Exiting Programme!\n");
            exit(0);
            break;
        default: printf("Invalid Choice chosen\n");
            break;
    }
} while (choice != 3);

}

void view_calender()
{
int is_leap_year( int year );        /* True if leap year */
int leap_years( int year );         /* The number of leap year */
int today_of( int y, int m, int d); /* The number of days since the                     beginning of the year */
long days( int y, int m, int d);   /* Total number of days */
void calendar(int y, int m);       /* display calendar at m y */

int year,month;

printf("Enter the Month(mm):  ");
scanf("%d", &month);
printf("Enter the Year(yyyy):  ");
scanf("%d", &year);
calendar(year, month);
return 0;


int isLeapYear( int y ) /* True if leap year */
{
return(y % 400 == 0) || ((y % 4 == 0) && (y % 100 != 0));
}

int leapYears( int y ) /* The number of leap year */
{
return y/4 - y/100 + y/400;
}

int TodayOf( int y, int m, int d) /* The number of days since the  beginning of the year */
{
static int DayOfMonth[] = 
    { -1,0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334};

return DayOfMonth[m] + d + ((m>2 && is_leap_year(y))? 1 : 0);
}

long Days( int y, int m, int d) /* Total number of days */
{
int last_year;

last_year = y - 1;

return 365L * last_year + leapy_years(last_year) + TodayOf(y,m,d);
}

void view_calendar() /* display calendar at m y */
{

int month[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
char* day[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday" "Friday", "Saturday"};   
int d;
int moti;
int yel;
int i; 

printf("Enter date in this format dd-mm-yyyy: ");
scanf("%d-%d-%d",  &d, &moti, &yel);

// correction for leap year


for (i = 1900; i < yel; i++)
    if (i % 4 == 0 && (i % 100 != 0 || i % 400 == 0))
        d += 366;
    else
        d += 365;

for (i = 0; i < moti - 1; i++) 
    d += month[i];

printf("This is a %s.\n", day[d % 7]);
return 0;
}
}
```

If the user selects option (2), the program must display the day on which the user's entered date falls.

For instance, if the user wants to know on which day 24th October 2021 falls, they must be prompted to enter the year (i.e. 2021), the month (i.e. 10 for October), and the date (i.e. 24).

The output must be the day of the week e.g. "Sunday".

The program, after executing option (1) or (2) must display the menu again.

Comment: And *what is the exact error message*? My error message says: `warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘exit’`

Comment: Also you've got functions returning value from `void`-returning functions and functions that are not returning a value from non-void functions... and one `printff` that I doubt that exists...

Comment: It appears you're (declaring and) defining functions inside `view_calender()`. C does not allow nested function definitions.

Comment: @pmg: C does allow nested function definitions. The C standard does not **define** nested function definitions, but it **allows** extensions. A better phrasing is that standard C does not support nested function definitions.

Comment: So what should i do

Comment: Don't edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. Your question was why you're getting warnings for `exit`; that question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

The source code you show gets a warning about an incompatible definition of `exit` because:

- `exit` is a reserved identifier; it should be used only for the standard library routine named `exit`.
- Your program does not include the `<stdlib.h>` that would provide a declaration of `exit`.
- Your program uses `exit` without a declaration for it. When a routine is used without a declaration, your compiler supplies a default declaration.
- The default declaration is for a function returning `int`, but the correct declaration for `exit` is a function returning nothing (`void`), so the compiler warnings you the declaration (provided by default) is incompatible with the built-in standard function.

To fix this, insert `#include <stdlib.h>` in your program.

Comment: I have inserted #include <stdlib.h> so this fixes the exit problem

Comment: May someone please re-write my code it is still giving me errors

Comment: @Lenny: the someone who needs to rewrite your code goes by the name "Lenny" on SO — it's your program; you need to fix the other errors you've created.  Track 'em down one by one, starting with the first one reported in each compilation.  Sometimes you can fix more than one at a time; sometimes, the first error triggers the others.